# Move UV island but snap active to pixels?

Tags: uv

Is there a simple way (and if not, what is the complex way) to select a whole UV island, and move it around in UV space but always align a chosen vertex (or even better, edge) to pixel grid? If I turn 'snap to pixels' on, my islands get deformed a lot when moving because I'm working on very low-res textures.

Comment: You could move one vertex, find out the transformation when it snaps to pixel, then move everything else on the island (w/o snapping) that precise amount. This is sort of the complex way...I'll post an answer if no one gives a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! This is probably what I will do if there's no faster method.